# Unique accesses on tree folders structure

Tags: sharepoint-server, unique, unique-permissions

I have a structure in a list that looks like below:

List 1

- SubList in a Folder 1.a
- SubList in a Folder 1.b
- SubList in a Folder 1.c
- ...
- SubList in a Folder 1.z

I set unique permissions (using groups) for List 1 and every SubList in a Folder 1.a, 1.b etc as they don't need to see the other content. Every list and sublist has unique permissions.

I need a way to cut the edit access to all the users at once (for all Folders/sublists) when is the cut-off date, so they don't edit the lists while we're closing the books.

I realized that even if i remove their access from List 1, because they have individual unique permissions to edit the sublist, they can still edit the sublists.

Is there a way to lock edit for all sublists in folders for all users at once?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the permissions of all users to all sublists as read permission.

You could use PowerShell. Here's a reference for you.

[Grant Permission to Folders in SharePoint Document Library using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/set-folder-permissions-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html#ixzz6Y6SOJUlH)